# Вывод данных из запроса в одной строке

Tags: oracle

Есть запрос, который из двух таблиц выводит данные

```
select t1.v_id, t2.tab1_id, t2.text
from 
tab1 t1
,tab2 t2
where t2.tab1_id = t1.id
```

Данные выводит в таком виде

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можно ли вывести данные в следующем виде?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, есть такой способ, называется `PIVOT`:

```
select *
  from (select t1.v_id, t2.tab1_id, t2.text
          from tab1 t1 ,tab2 t2
         where t2.tab1_id = t1.id)
pivot (max(text) for tab1_id in (16767, 16742, 16747, -- и так далее))
```

Единственное, что непонятно в ваших данных, - откуда берутся `field_1`, `field_2`, `field_3` и прочие. В моем запросе вместо них будут идти `16767`, `16742`, `16747`, но смысл, я думаю, понятен.

Comment: Field_1 2 и т.д. это замена как раз таки  16767 и т.д. можно ли заодно заменить числа на field 1 2 и т.д

Comment: Можно, разрешаю ;)

Comment: Это была шутка, конечно. Где и как у вас хранится привязка чисел и названий? Просто приджойните их (или другим способом поменяйте запрос-источник).

Comment: У меня в подзапросе во `FROM` ваш запрос, ели вы заметили. Подставьте туда что-то другое, и поправьте `PIVOT` соответственно.

Comment: Спасибо, чуть подправил ваш ответ. Названия сделал так 16767 AS field_1
        , 16742 AS field_2
        , 16747 AS field_3
        ***
        ,16454 AS field_n